# Latest Linux distros fail while installing or while booting on a Dell XPS15-9560 laptop

Tags: linux, bios

I have a Dell XPS15-9560 laptop.  I ran Ubuntu 16.04 on it for two years with minimal problems.  After I sent it in for service (battery was swelling, a fairly common problem on this model) I moved to Ubuntu 19.04 again with minimal problems.  A couple of days ago I got a popup asking if I wanted to upgrade to 19.10.  After upgrading to 19.10 it would hang while booting displaying the Ubuntu splash screen and wait cursor.  I tried a fresh install of 19.10 from bootable USB, but had the same problem.

I tried to install OpenSUSE LEAP 15.1, but the installer shuts the laptop down before installing anything.  It displays a green progress bar for a couple of minutes and then shuts down without installing the OS.

I also tried Fedora 31 but the installer hung while trying to display GNOME.

I've verified that Ubuntu 19.04 and 16.04 both install and run.

I'm wondering if the latest Linux distros require some change to the BIOS settings.  If I remember correctly when I first installed Ubuntu 16.04 I had to change the SATA Operation from RAID on to AHCI, and possibly one other change having to do with UEFI vs Legacy BIOS.  (I also tried reinstalling Windows 10 with the current BIOS settings, but it would not boot so I'm thinking I made one other change to BIOS settings that prevented Win10 from booting.)

After all of that frustration I'm back to Ubuntu 16.04 and waiting for CrashPlan to restore > 200 GB of files.

Do the latest linux distros require a tweak to BIOS settings?

Comment: I ended up installing Win10 as the host OS because VMWare player wouldn't run on Ubuntu 16.04 (and VirtualBox is too bug-ridden).  Now I run Ubuntu as the guest OS in VMWare player.  Sad that Linux won't work as the host OS on Dell XPS15 hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a bug in recent versions of the Linux kernel.  An explanation is given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185601/ubuntu-19-10-upgrade-has-destroyed-my-laptop-is-there-any-way-to-recover/1185795#1185795).

There's really no way to know if this bug will be a problem on your hardware short of trying to install a new Linux version and if the install works then seeing if it will boot.

This is a serious risk to Linux users.